# Recover deleted .SKETCH files

Tags: mac, storage, data-recovery, file-recovery

I recently deleted some sketch files that I would like to try to get back if I can. I trashed them over a month ago, I used stellar phoenix to attempt to recover them, and it found the files. It did ask file size when creating a .sketch header, unlike the pre-configured headers (which have an exact file size set). The files are around 5.0 mb, so thats what I set for the max file size. When the files appear after recovery, the finder shows they're all (but one file) 5.0 mb. I try to open one, but then I receive "The document "filename.SKETCH" could not be opened." message. Am I approaching this all wrong, or are they just gone?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All file recovery software does the same thing: searches the disk for places where files are but the catalog says are free.

The single most important thing to do to ensure that you can recover an accidentally deleted file is recoverable is to do **nothing** to the HD. If it is the OS disk then just using the computer runs the risk of the OS writing to some or all of the space that the deleted file occupies.

So when you recover a file you should always recover it to another volume. As recovering to the same volume can be overwriting other files you may need to recover.

After a month I am surprised there was even 5MB left that was recoverable. If that was all the recovery software found and the files are not openable it is unlikely they ever will be.

The first time this happened to me I went out and bought a backup drive and software. It's a lot easier than file recovery.

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck with [File Salvage](https://www.subrosasoft.com/product/filesalvage/) or [Data Rescue](https://www.prosofteng.com/datarescue4/). Both have free trials. However, as another user said, working from the disk where the files were lost decreases the chances of recovery.